# Spring Boot JPA - Find By Composite Unique Columns

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have created the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE public."TB_KEY"
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"TB_KEY_seq"'::regclass),
    "UNIQUE_ID" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "VERSION" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ATTRIBUTE_NAME" character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "MDD_KEY_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "MDD_KEY_unique" UNIQUE ("UNIQUE_MDD_ID", "VERSION")
)
```

I created the following entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"TB_KEY\"")
public class Key {

    private int id;
    private String uniqueId;
    private String version;
    private String attributeName;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1, sequenceName = "\"TB_KEY_seq\"", name = "key_id_seq")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "key_id_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "\"ID\"", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"UNIQUE_ID\"")
    public String getUniqueMDDId() {
        return uniqueId;
    }
    public void setUniqueMDDId(String uniqueMDDId) {
        this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"VERSION\"")
    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }
    public void setVersion(String version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name = "\"ATTRIBUTE_NAME\"")
    public String getAttributeName() {
        return attributeName;
    }
    public void setAttributeName(String attributeName) {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }

}
```

Using Spring JPA respository, I want to find by composite unique constarint columns without using native query
(For ex : I want to find a row in Key entity by UniqueId and Version columns)

How do I achieve using findBy method?